# Rails can't convert Hash into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

After setup the current_user

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.first(conditions: ['auth_token = :token or oauth_token = :token', { token: cookies[:auth_token] }]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end
```

rails raised

> can't convert Hash into Integer

This method was working in rails 3 now on rails 5 raised this, someone can spare a hint about this issue?

Comment: Yea, there have been **a lot** of changes between Rails 3 and Rails 5. This syntax no longer works, but [there are plenty of others](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned: Rails' finder syntax has changed a lot.

Try something more like:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.where('auth_token = :token or oauth_token = :token', token: cookies[:auth_token]).first if cookies[:auth_token].present?
end
```

(Note: I have not tested this code - fixing bugs is an exercise for the reader)